# ConTeXt: custom \intertext

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal-alignment, align, context

In a ConTeXt file, I would like to insert a line of text inside `\eqalign`.

When I use `\intertext`:

```
\starttext
\startalignment[middle]
$\eqalign{
  a &= b \cr
  \intertext{and}
  b &= c \cr
}$
\stopalignment
\stoptext
```

I get left-aligned equations with large vertical spacing around
the inserted line:
[image: current result]

I need a custom macro based on `\intertext` that:

- keeps the equations centered like all of my equations are,
- does not add vertical spacing.

The result should look like this:
[image: wanted result]

My attempts at hacking [ConTeXt's definition](https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkiv/math-ali.mkiv) of `\intertext`:

```
\def\intertext#1%
  {\noalign{\math_intertext{#1}}}

\unexpanded\def\math_intertext#1%
  {\penalty\postdisplaypenalty
   \afterdisplayspace
   \vbox{\forgetall\noindent#1\par}%
   \penalty\predisplaypenalty
   \beforedisplayspace}
```

were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\intertext` command adds the normal formula space set with the `spacebefore` and `spaceafter` keys from `\setupformula`.

```
\setupformula
  [spacebefore=small,
   spaceafter=none]

\starttext

\startformula
    \startmathalignment
        \NC a \EQ b \NR
        \intertext{\midaligned{and}}
        \NC b \EQ c \NR
    \stopmathalignment
\stopformula

\stoptext
```